# XMLSerialization issue

Tags: xml-serialization

I need to generate the XML file which will be consumed by the external application. And I have observed that it depends on ordering of the namespace defined in the XML. Since the xml is consumed by external application, I don't have the exact error details.

Below is the sample code

```
        [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Xsd2Code", "3.4.0.32990")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://mycompany.com/2010/package")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("Catalog", Namespace="http://mycompany.com/2010/package", IsNullable=false)]
    public partial class PackageT : System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {
    }
```

Extension class written in order to include custom schemalocation

```
public partial class PackageT
{
    [XmlAttributeAttribute("schemaLocation", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string xsiSchemaLocation = "http://mycompany.com/2010/catalog.xsd";
}
```

Code to serialize the object to XML

```
 XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        namespaces.Add("xml", "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"); 
        namespaces.Add("test", "http://mycompany.com/2010/package");                
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PackageT));          
        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("package.xml");
        serializer.Serialize(writer, catalog, namespaces);
        writer.Flush();
        writer.Close();
```

Generated XML ( not working)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test:Catalog 
  xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
  d1p1:schemaLocation="http://mycompany.com/2010/catalog.xsd"
 xmlns:d1p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:test="http://mycompany.com/2010/package">
 ....
 </test:Catalog>
```

EXpected XML which is working

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test:Catalog d1p1:schemaLocation="http://mycompany.com/2010/catalog.xsd"
 xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
 xmlns:d1p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:test="http://mycompany.com/2010/package">
 ....
 </test:Catalog>
```

Please help me!!

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the element name and namespace for the root you can generate the XML you're looking for. Modify PackageT as below:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Catalog", Namespace = "http://mycompany.com/2010/package") ]
public partial class PackageT
{
    [XmlAttribute("schemaLocation", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string xsiSchemaLocation = "http://mycompany.com/2010/catalog.xsd";
}
```

and the output becomes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test:Catalog xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
              d1p1:schemaLocation="http://mycompany.com/2010/catalog.xsd"
              xmlns:d1p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xmlns:test="http://mycompany.com/2010/package" />
```